# XCode Formatting: Grey Source Code

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I can't figure out what this grey text indicates or if it's a glitch in XCode. I'm using the default color theme of XCode 4.3. If you have experienced this, what was it about?

[image]

I can't get rid of it by deleting the code, so it doesn't seem to be anything indicated by the code that's written—it seems to be tied to a position in the editor. It affects a fixed number of characters that follows the source code text that's at that position. Is it a marker or indication of something, or is this a glitch?

Comment: did you want s single bar (bitwise OR), '|' or did you mean logical OR, the double bar, '||' ?

Comment: out of interest did the grey highlight go away when you changed it to logical OR?

Comment: @user1432128 Did that fix your problem? Still seems like a bug to me. The code highlighter should know how to parse bitwise OR correctly.

Comment: It's gone, but … man … I messed with that area so much trying to get to the source of the problem. EDIT: But I think it was a glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use xcode 4.1 with c++ and I've never had this problem, but I have had similar problems with other text editors. The first thing to check is, does your code compile and run? I'm not 100% familiar with C#, but that looks correct. If that works, sometimes highlighting the line of code that is weirdly colored will cause the IDE to re-color the text. Or you can look in Preferences > Fonts & Colors > Source Editor to see if you have any grey syntax highlighting. Finally, you can try to quit and restart xcode and see if that solves the problem. This looks like some sort of glitch. Maybe apple will have a better solution? Hope that helps!

Comment: FYI, that's Objective-C not C#.

Comment: Yes, Objective-C, and for the record everything compiled and ran properly!

Comment: Sorry I meant obj-C. Admittedly, I thought C# was obj-C. oops :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a glitch to me. What happens when you restart Xcode?

Comment: It went away after restart. Now I think it was just a glitch. I also happened to change the code in that area pretty significantly (and XCode has shown some latency in applying color changes), so I can't say for sure, but I'm happy to have it gone.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens again, you may be having problems with the indexer. Have you got multiple targets in your project, or multiple projects in a workspace? If so, make sure they all build completely cleanly - a failure indexing one target can mess up code completion on another.

You might also try deleting your project's **DerivedData** folder